# How to make Java desktop application that never lets the system sleep and runs in background?

Tags: java, windows, mouseevent, sleep, desktop-application

I am new to Java programming and I know basic syntax of Java and can write programs.
I want to make desktop application in java that never lets the system sleep. I want that application to run in background and should not disturb the user flow.

I figured out some keyboard keys can be pressed internally which does not affect the flow like F13 F14 not shown to user but can be used internally.

Also I came with this java program that moves the mouse to its same position after some seconds so that system does not sleep.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Mal{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Robot mal = new Robot();
        while(true){
            mal.delay(1000 * 60); 
            mal.mouseMove(mouseLoc.x, mouseLoc.y);
        }
    }
}
```

I am curious to know how to make desktop app for windows using Java. 
Like when user clicks on the app it get activated and keep running in the background until close by the user and it should never let the PC sleep either my moving mouse or by clicking special keys.

Useful links, code and path for development is required.

Thank You!

Comment: Why don't you just set the settings on Windows to never sleep?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using java.awt.Robot: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

As the documentation notes, this will not work in all environments, because allowing user-space programs to emulate user input is a bit of a security issue.